# reverse inventory order on demand

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a playbook that I have been using for a while.  The playbook defines certain parameters and variables for an East and a West location.  West has always been the primary location and East the backup.  We are now switching the logic to where the customer is located, that will be the Primary location.  I am trying to reverse the inventory hosts when the location is on the East Coast that way the East Coast equipment will get the primary setup then the West Coast.  I have tried the following without any luck.  According to the documentation this is the correct syntax for reversing the order of the inventory file.

The offending line appears to be:

when: location == "east"
order: reverse_inventory
^ here

```
- hosts: cisco_lab
  when: location == "east"
    order: reverse_inventory

  ......Rest of playbook
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `order` be on the same indentation level as `hosts`?

Comment: I only want that line reversed when location = east, the rest of the playbook should stay the same.

Comment: When I put the order in the same indentation as the hosts.  I get the following error: ERROR! 'when' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *ternary*, e.g. given the inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
[cisco_lab]
host1
host2
host3
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
---
- hosts: cisco_lab
  order: "{{ (location == 'east')|ternary('reverse_inventory', 'inventory') }}"
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

executes the *east* location in reverse order

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -e location=east

PLAY [cisco_lab] ***********************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [host3] => 
  inventory_hostname: host3
ok: [host2] => 
  inventory_hostname: host2
ok: [host1] => 
  inventory_hostname: host1
```